# PHP - isset($_POST['rejectSeed']) is not detected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Does not go through with this code. I have a modal in which has a submit button and every time I have to click the submit button there is no action or what so ever to insert it in the database. I have the same code in the same file that has the same function but the other one works. So the database insertion is not the problem.

```
    //REJECTED PROJECT & CHECKING FOR REASON 
if(isset($_POST['rejectSeed'])){
    echo "HUY";
        $query3="UPDATE projects 
        SET project_status = '7', reason = '".$_POST['reasonSeed']."' 
        WHERE id =".$idProj."";      

        retrieveTable($query3);
        header('Location: listprojectsprojectproposal.php');
}
```

[image]

```
echo "  
<div class='modal fade' id='modalRejectSeed' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
          <h4 class='modal-title'>Reject ".$strings["project"].": ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0]."</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
          <h5>Please state the reason why Seed Company rejected the project ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0].". (eg. Insufficient)</h5>

            <div class='input-group'>
                <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1' style='width:500px;'>Reason for Rejection:</span>
                <input type='text' id='reasonSeed' name='reasonSeed' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' placeholder='' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
            <input type='submit' id='rejectSeed' class='btn btn-primary' name='rejectSeed'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ";
```

Comment: You're opening yourself up to massive XSS and SQL injection attacks. You need to escape data going to HTML and use parameterized SQL queries.

Comment: If you ever tried to `var_dump($_POST)` you will see that `'rejectSeed'` is not there. Oh and apparently nothing of this code is inside a `<form>` so what are you submitting?

Comment: @Xorifelse Hi, the method $_POST is located at the same file as the code Ive writted below. Do I still need to get it inside a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a form tag in your model

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class='modal fade' id='modalRejectSeed' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
      <h4 class='modal-title'>Reject ".$strings["project"].": ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0]."</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <h5>Please state the reason why Seed Company rejected the project ".$projectDetail->pro_name[0].". (eg. Insufficient)</h5>

        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1' style='width:500px;'>Reason for Rejection:</span>
            <input type='text' id='reasonSeed' name='reasonSeed' class='form-control' style='width:500px;' placeholder='' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
        <input type='submit' id='rejectSeed' class='btn btn-primary' name='rejectSeed'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did not know that form is required in submitting. Your answer really helped.